# Failure sending mail Exception while send with SmtpClient

Tags: c#, .net

C# I am trying to send mail with following code. OS is windows 2008 server. SMTP is installed.

```
           MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
            string[] recipientslist = recipients.Split(';');
            foreach (string recipient in recipientslist)
            {
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(recipient))
                {
                    System.Net.Mail.MailAddress mailAddress = 
                        new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(recipient);
                    message.To.Add(mailAddress.Address);
                }
            }
            message.From = new MailAddress(sender);
            message.Subject = subject;
            message.Body = body;
            SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient();
    smtpClient.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.PickupDirectoryFromIis;
    smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
    smtpClient.Send(message);
```

In web.config

```
  <system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp deliveryMethod="PickupDirectoryFromIis">
        <network host="localhost" port="25" defaultCredentials="true" />
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
  </system.net>
```

Even smtp is installed,
I m getting Exception: Failure sending mail.
Stack Trace:    at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message)....

==========================================================================================

The other scenario when SMTP is not installed, it giving me the exception **Cannot get IIS pickup directory**

Any help is highly appreciable.

Thanks**strong text**

Comment: those snippets are not very helpful.. some pointers: can you connect to local smtp using telnet? paste the exception details

Comment: Does your IIS user have write permission to the pickup directory? Also, have you tried using the Network delivery method instead of PickupDirectoryFromIis?

Comment: @Osama: I can connect to local smtp using telnet. Exception is not informative "Exception: Failure sending mail.
Stack Trace:    at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message)
   at QH.ExchangeProtection.Util.CommonUtil.SendMail(String sender, String recipients, String subject, String body)"

Comment: @JamieSee: I am newbie to c# and networking concepts. with the Network delivery method giving same exception

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer..

Permission is needed to default IIS pickup directory. I just added permissions for Network service and done.

Following is the check list that should be verified before sending mail..
http://torontoprogrammer.ca/2011/04/fixing-the-cannot-get-iis-pickup-directory-error-in-asp-net/

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is an anti-virus program, QH Exchange Protection, interfering with sending mail from the application. Contact your system administrator about this. If you are the administrator of your system, you'll need to find out how to tell Quick Heal's product not to do this.

Comment: Yeah, and how you know that it is this specific program installed there?